# Looking for literature about graphics pipeline optimization

Tags: opengl, architecture, graphics, optimization, pipeline

I am looking for some books, articles or tutorials about graphics architecture and graphics pipeline optimizations. It shouldn't be too old (2008 or newer) - the newer, the better.

I have found something in [Optimising the Graphics Pipeline, NVIDIA, Koji Ashida] - too old, [Real-time rendering, Akenine Moller], [OpenGL Bindless Extensions, NVIDIA, Jeff Bolz], [Efficient multifragment effects on graphics processing units, Louis Frederic Bavoil] and some internet discussions. But there is not too much information and I want to read more.

It should contain something about application, driver, memory and shader units communication and data transfers. About vertices and attributes. Also pre and post T&L cache (if they still exist in nowadays architectures) etc. I don't need anything about textures, frame buffers and rasterization.

It can also be about OpenGL (not about DirecX) and optimizing extensions (not old extensions like VBOs, but newer like vertex_buffer_unified_memory).

Answer (score 1):

These are all free.

[GPU Gems 1](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_part01.html)
[GPU Gems 2](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_part01.html)
[GPU Gems 3](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_part01.html)

[The Graphics Programming Black Book](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1698.asp)
[ShaderX](http://tog.acm.org/resources/shaderx/)

EDIT: I misread your question. I feel the most useful one here will be the Black Book, though you might find some use in the others.

Comment: Thanks. I have all GPU Gems, but i haven't read them yet. I will try them. Only problem is, that all of these books are old :(